# How to set time manually when @UpdateTimestamp and @CreationTimestamp is used in entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-migration

I am doing data migration from legacy system to my system.

In my application, I have used @UpdateTimestamp and @CreationTimestamp to auto update date time for my entity. this works fine.

When I do data migration from other system, I want create time and last update time should be as it was in legacy system.

This is not happening even if I set time manually in entity. It always takes system time.

Is there any way to disable this auto update for certain call like data migration?

Comment: I think it needs more clarity, as what I am getting from above, your migration DB query will not be affected due to the used annotations and if you are using some scripting based on java, then just remove the annotation, deploy the code, run that script & re-deploy with annotations.

Comment: I'd say that database migrations shouldn't be done via hibernate but rather directly on the database

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes you are correct. but in our case, almost 70% data transformation processing required so we are going with Spring boot batch

Comment: From what I could find, the values for the annotations are set at a point in the code where you can't suppress it anymore. There also doesn't seem to be any kind of configuration attached to each annotation. This leaves you only with what @KamlendraPandey suggested. Remove the annotations, perform migration, add annotations back